# How to access a table in a frameset

Tags: javascript

I don't know how I can access a table in a tree frame. Can you help me?

```
 <html>
    <head>
       <script>
            alert( window.frames[1].document.getElementById('row'));
        </script>
    </head>
    <FRAMESET cols="90%, 10%" onload="start()">
      <FRAMESET rows="70%,*">
          <FRAME src="https://www.orias.fr/" id="details">
          <FRAME src="traitement.php" id="traitement">
      </FRAMESET>
      <FRAME src="pagination.php" id="pages">

    </FRAMESET>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it one of the local files or the orias.fr site? Because if it's the last one, you can't.

Comment: @GerbenJacobs — `frames[1]`

Comment: yes is not a local file ,the file from other site

Answer (score 0):

You can't access a frame before it is added to the DOM, and you can't access a document in a frame until it has loaded.

You are calling a `start` function `onload` but haven't defined it. Define it.

```
function start() {
  alert( window.frames[1].document.getElementById('row'));
}
```

Comment: i define it but the problem not resorved